# Increase web.py simultaneous calls

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services, web.py

I have a web service in web.py and I noticed from logs that it is limited by 10 simultaneous calls. When the 11th call comes and the other 10 did not responded yet, the client need to wait for the server. How could I increase this limit to more simultaneous calls?

Here is my code:

```
import web
urls = (
    '/query', 'query',
    '/query?(.*)', 'query',
    '/ingest', 'ingest',
)

class query:
    def GET(self):
        global calls
        resp_json = do_some_heavy_processing()

        return resp_json

application = web.application(urls, globals())#.wsgifunc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Comment: Is this still an issue, or have you found the solution? You didn't mention if you see this when accessing the web app directly or if it's running behind e.g. an Apache web server...

Comment: it is still happening and in both directly and behind nginx

Comment: you can put this heavy_processing in a queue,such as Celery